# Can I tell the compiler to consider a control path closed with regards to return value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, g++, warnings

Say I have the following function:

```
Thingy& getThingy(int id)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < something(); ++i )
    {
        // normal execution guarantees that the Thingy we're looking for exists
        if ( thingyArray[i].id == id )
            return thingyArray[i];
    }

    // If we got this far, then something went horribly wrong and we can't recover.
    // This function terminates the program.
    fatalError("The sky is falling!");

    // Execution will never reach this point.
}
```

Compilers will typically complain at this, saying that "not all control paths return a value". Which is technically true, but the control paths that don't return a value abort the program before the function ends, and are therefore semantically correct. Is there a way to tell the compiler (VS2010 in my case, but I'm curious about others as well) that a certain control path is to be ignored for the purposes of this check, without suppressing the warning completely or returning a nonsensical dummy value at the end of the function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can annotate the function `fatalError` (its declaration) to let the compiler know it will never return.

In C++11, this would be something like:

```
[[noreturn]] void fatalError(std::string const&);
```

Pre C++11, you have compiler specific attributes, such as GCC's:

```
void fatalError(std::string const&) __attribute__((noreturn));
```

or Visual Studio's:

```
__declspec(noreturn) void fatalError(std::string const&);
```

Comment: Or, for Visual C++, `__declspec(noreturn)`

Comment: This does not apply as the function will only return nothing, when the exceptional path is taken.

Comment: @Nobody That fatalError is declared to never return doesn't mean that getThingy can't in the cases fatalError isn't called.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Either I misunderstood you (because of too much negations) or you are saying the same thing as I wanted to say.

Comment: @Nobody Maybe you're commenting on a comment that was removed, but it sounded like you were saying `noreturn` doesn't apply because getThingy returns data in some cases. I was just pointing out that it's fatalError that's declared `noreturn`, so getThingy will be ok to  not return only in the case that fatalError is called.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Now I see my mistake: I somehow was thinking all the time that `getThingy` should get `noreturn`, which would make no sense. I can't believe I overlooked it all the time.

Comment: @Matthieu: I have not seen that before (and a quick search of n2691 does not reveal it). What section should I be looking at?

Comment: @LokiAstari:  C++11 §7.6.3[dcl.attr.noreturn].  I think C++11 attributes can only go before the declaration, though:  `[[noreturn]] void fatalError(std::string const&);`

Comment: The examples in the standard put the `[[ noreturn ]]` at the front (not the back of the declaration) ie before `void`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Oups, sorry. I must admit I am still a rookie when it comes to C++11. You mentionned `__declspec` before and I believe it also goes to the front, doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes, `__declspec(noreturn)` appears before the return type; it may be allowed to appear elsewhere; my knowledge of all allowable combinations of syntax is weak.  :-)  [As for C++11... I am the same... I use Visual C++ 95% of the time, and if it doesn't support a C++11 feature, then I don't know anything about that feature...]

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you throw an exception? That would solve the problem and it would force the calling method to deal with the exception.

If you did manage to haggle the warning out some way or other, you are still left with having to do something with the function that calls getThingy(). What happens when getThingy() fails? How will the caller know? What you have here is an exception (conceptually) and your design should reflect that.

Comment: I can confirm that my gcc (4.6.2) does not trigger the warning when a throw is encountered before the closing `}`. If you want to stick with your code you could simply add a `throw 0;` or something equal after `fatalError...`.

Comment: The comment states "If we got this far, then something went horribly wrong and we can't recover."  In that case, termination of the program (e.g. via an assertion or a "fatalError") is reasonable.

Comment: @anio: I personally use functions to `throw` so that I can do some formatting and improvement of the error messages (gathering a stack trace for example). It's richer than a bare `throw` statement, thus makes for a nicer debugging experience.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis You are right, an assertion would be appropriate. However, an assertion doesn't let you do any last minute cleanup, that an exception might afford.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a run time assertion in lieu of your `fatalError` routine.  This would just look like:

```
Thingy& getThingy(int id)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < something(); ++i )
    {
        if ( thingyArray[i].id == id )
            return thingyArray[i];
    }
    // Clean up and error condition reporting go here.
    assert(false);
}
```

Comment: This would work but would have the not so nice side effect of a core dump.

Comment: A core dump may be useful if the condition which gave rise to the failure is sufficiently rare.

Comment: It will work only in debug build. In release build assert do nothing so warning persist.